# My Looping is Jumping one Row using Next

Tags: vba, excel

Thanks in advance.
I have this VBA Code which I've been running for quite a long time now but it's not working as intended. I have some formulas that divide some values and the intent of this code is to send all the information if it meets a criteria into another Tab so I can protect my data.

The problem is, whenever I run the macro, the "Next" Function is **jumping** to the next row once it copies the first and therefore I can't copy and paste all the rows that meets the criteria.

Here is the code:

```
Sub ENTREGUES()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
Answer = MsgBox("Gostaria de Enviar as Entregas Finalizadas?", vbQuestion + 
vbYesNo + vbDefaultButton2, "TRACKING >>> ENTREGUES")
If Answer = vbNo Then Exit Sub

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

Dim wsT As Worksheet, wsD As Worksheet
Set wsT = Sheets("TRACKING")
Set wsD = Sheets("ENTREGUES")

wsT.Unprotect "sds"
wsD.Unprotect "sds"

Dim lastrowT as Long, nextrowD As Long

lastrowT = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsT.Range("D:D")) + 6

For i = 6 To lastrowT

    If wsT.Cells(i, "AS").Value <> "" Then
        wsT.Rows(i).Copy
            wsT.Rows(i).Copy
            nextrowD = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsD.Range("D:D")) + 3
                wsD.Cells(nextrowD, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsT.Rows(i).Delete
    End If

Next i

wsT.Protect "sds", True, True
wsD.Protect "sds", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
        , AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True

Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Here are the images so you can see when the Next I runs it jumps to the next Row:

Images:
[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

And then it keeps Jumping until the End Sub leaving (in the example) 3 Rows behind.

I've been struggling to find a solution for 3 days and can't figure it out.

I tried to change the way VBA is counting the rows or trying to select all of them before copying but I didn't succeed.

Can anybode enlight me what am I missing please?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Loop backwards when deleting to avoid this problem.

Comment: Just like explained below. Think about it like this: You are inside the loop on example Row 5, you delete the row, Row 6 now becomes Row 5, but you are done processing Row 5, you move to the next one (6) but since Row 6 became row 5 inside the loop, it got skipped. Loop backwards so this doesn't happen. When you loop backwards, you are on example row 10, and you delete it, row 11 becomes row 10, but you are looping backwards, you already processed row 11 before, you now move to row 9, therefore nothing gets skipped.

Comment: Ricardo A, thank you for  your explanation. I was about to ask it and then I saw your comment. It makes sense to me now!

Answer (score 4):

You should loop from bottom to the top when deleting rows, as when you delete a row the row below shifts up one row and as such the For Loop misses that one row, but if your For Loop goes from bottom up, when rows shift up they are still included in the loop, like below:

```
For i = lastrowT To 6 Step -1

    If wsT.Cells(i, "AS").Value <> "" Then
        wsT.Rows(i).Copy
            wsT.Rows(i).Copy
            nextrowD = WorksheetFunction.CountA(wsD.Range("D:D")) + 3
                wsD.Cells(nextrowD, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        wsT.Rows(i).Delete
    End If

Next i
```

Comment: OMG Thank you SOO Much! It worked Wonders!! S2